# MySQL で、データベースに対して実行された DML (insert, update, delete) の一覧を取得することはできる?

Tags: mysql

MySQL で、不可解なデータ不整合が突如発生したとします。データベースに対して実行された、直近の DML (insert, update, delete 文) の一覧を取得できないものかと考えました。

これは、可能でしょうか?

バージョンが重要ならば、ひとまず最新(8.x 系)を想定しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

やりたいことは、こういうことですかね？

https://colo-ri.jp/develop/2012/05/mysql-query-log-setting.html